# echo "$var" prints blank space

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I was basically trying to compare two files and as part of that I assigned the cksum of the file to a variable . But when I try to compare it, it did not work. I realized that when I tried to read the variable nothing gets printed out

The below commands worked just fine

```
s.joseph@VA-S-JOSEPH-900 /cygdrive/c/users/Anuprita
$ test=`cksum interface2 | awk -F" " '{ print $1 }'`

s.joseph@VA-S-JOSEPH-900 /cygdrive/c/users/Anuprita
$ echo "$test"
3021988741
```

But when these are part of a script and I try to `echo $var`, nothing gets printed

```
$ for i in `ls interface*`; 
  do chksum1=`cksum $i | awk -F" " '{ print "'$1'" }'`; 
  echo "$chksum1"; 
  done

s.joseph@VA-S-JOSEPH-900 /cygdrive/c/users/Anuprita
$
```

I am using bash shell

Without assigning it to any variable, the output is as shown below

for i in interface*; do echo "interface=\"$i\""; cksum "$i"; done

interface="interface11"
4113442291 111 interface11
interface="interface17"
1275738681 111 interface17
interface="interface2"
3021988741 186 interface2

Looks like it is an issue only with bash on cygwin. The script seems to be working just fine on unix

for i in `ls interface*`;    do  chksum1=`cksum $i | awk -F" " '{ print $1 }'`;    echo $i, $chksum1;    done 
interface1, 4294967295
interface2, 4294967295

Comment: BTW, see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); `for i in interface*` is both faster and **much** less buggy than ```for i in $(ls interface*)```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
for i in ls interface*; do echo "interface=$i"; chksum1=$(cksum $i | awk -F" " '{ print "'$1'" }'); echo "$chksum1"; done
```

I like adding the echo statement to verify your getting what you think with the ls statement and the variable assignment should use $(cmd) or `cmd`

Cheers

Comment: running the script with bash -x SCRIPTNAME generates cryptic output, but is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your 2nd script:

```
print "'$1'"
```

is a completely different statement from what you have in your first one:

```
print $1
```

Think about it and ask yourself why you changed it and what it is you're trying to achieve. Also `man awk` and see `g` at http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for what `print "'$1'"` does.

Best I can tell without and provided sample input your script should be written:

```
for i in interface*; do chksum1=$(cksum "$i" | awk '{ print $1 }'); echo "$chksum1"; done
```

Comment: Thank you . This was my fist post and got so many responses. Thank you. Not seeing any output I tried print "'$1'" , but that was a mistake I intended to just to $1.

Comment: Anyways I did try the script you provided, but the results are same, just blank lines getting printed

Comment: The only way that script can produce no output is if it has no input. What does `for i in interface*; do echo "interface=\"$i\""; cksum "$i"; done` output? Edit your question to show the answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks Ed, now I see the cksum being printed out

Comment: for i in interface*; do echo "interface=\"$i\""; cksum "$i"; done
interface="interface11"
4113442291 111 interface11
interface="interface17"
1275738681 111 interface17
interface="interface2"
3021988741 186 interface2

Comment: edit your question to format the script/code you added properly using the editor's `{}` button or adding 4 blanks at the start of each line - just like you did for your original scripts and data. You can delete your comment containing the script+output since that can't be formatted.

Comment: OK, now what does `What does for i in interface*; do echo "interface=\"$i\""; cksum "$i" | awk '{print $1}'; done output?`. See how we're stepping through the commands to debug the issue?

Comment: Thanks Ed, it seems like my script works just fine on unix and the issue is only seen with bash on cygwin

Comment: Run the script segments I suggested to debug it where you're having the issue.